# Why Spring does not find my Bean when I use multi-module maven project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have my project where `repository` and its tests - `repository.tests` are in separate modules. I like organising my project this way. The problem is that when I try to run tests Spring says there is no such bean. Detailed error message below. I don't get what dark magic Spring does here and why it run out of mana.

> [ERROR] shouldReturnAll  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< ERROR!
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

What I tried so far:

- putting the test class and the repository classes in the same package (however, they put into their place in the directory structure. Tests go to `src/test/java` while repository goes `src/main/java`) --> the same error message
- put repository test into the same module where the repository is --> it causes circular dependencies due to that `application` project should be included (it might indicates a problem, but still can't wrap my head around)
- I did my best to read through the relevant docs, but Spring's docs a bit messy for me still, and possibly I haven't found that half sentence I need... :S
- I added `@Repository` annotation to the repository interface, but the error message hasn't changed
- I took a good sleep --> I still don't have any idea what is wrong here :)

Project structure looks like below, and the problematic part is the `repositories` and `repository.tests`

```
com.encyclopedia-galactica.sourceformats:application
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:entities
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:entities.tests
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:dtos
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:dtos.tests
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:mappers.interfaces
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:mappers.implementations
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:mappers.tests
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:controllers
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:controllers.tests
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:repositories
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:repositories.tests
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:services
+- com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats:services.tests
```

pom.xml of `repositories`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
    <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
    <name>repositories</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
            <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

pom.xml of `repositories.tests`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
    <artifactId>repositories.tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
            <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.encyclopeia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
            <artifactId>repositories</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.encyclopedia-galactica.sourceformats</groupId>
            <artifactId>application</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Test class (it is placed in `src/test/java`, but package name is the same as the repository class:

```java
package com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;
import com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.entities.SourceFormat;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.application.SourceFormatServiceApplication.class)
public class FindAllTests {

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

  @Autowired
  private SourceFormatRepository repository;

  public FindAllTests() {
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnAll() {

    // Arrange
    SourceFormat sf1 = new SourceFormat(100L, "asd");
    SourceFormat sf2 = new SourceFormat(200L, "asd2");
    this.testEntityManager.persist(sf1);
    this.testEntityManager.persist(sf2);

    // Act 
    List<SourceFormat> sourceFormats = (List<SourceFormat>) this.repository.findAll();

    // Assert
    assertThat(sourceFormats.size()).isEqualTo(2);
  }

}
```

Repository base:

```java
package com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat;

import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SourceFormatBaseRepository<T, ID> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {
  <S extends T> S save(S entity);

  Iterable<T> findAll();
}
```

Repository:

```java
package com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat;

import com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.entities.SourceFormat;

public interface SourceFormatRepository extends SourceFormatBaseRepository<SourceFormat, Long> {
}
```

Error message: (sorry for the formatting, it seems SO changed something in the blockquote since it doesn't show the content using monospace fonts)

> [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 1
> source file to
> /Users/andrascsanyi/Dev/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/target/test-classes
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @
> repositories.tests --- [INFO] [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------- [INFO]  T E S T S [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Running
> com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests
> 09:05:31.009 [main] DEBUG
> .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __
> _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \  \/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )   '  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
> =========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)
>
> 2022-07-24 09:05:31.864  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> c.e.s.r.sourceformat.FindAllTests        : Starting FindAllTests using
> Java 18.0.2 on Andrass-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 43466 (started by
> andrascsanyi in
> /Users/andrascsanyi/Dev/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests)
> 2022-07-24 09:05:31.865  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> c.e.s.r.sourceformat.FindAllTests        : No active profile set,
> falling back to 1 default profile: "default" 2022-07-24 09:05:32.383
> INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2022-07-24 09:05:32.400  INFO 43466
> --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA
> repository interfaces. 2022-07-24 09:05:32.481  INFO 43466 --- [
> main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing
> 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version 2022-07-24
> 09:05:32.757  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database:
> url='jdbc:h2:mem:a66d2659-af0d-4752-b47b-5d96c1968039;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false',
> username='sa' 2022-07-24 09:05:33.331  INFO 43466 --- [
> main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2022-07-24 09:05:33.414  INFO
> 43466 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    :
> HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final 2022-07-24
> 09:05:33.711  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
> Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final} 2022-07-24 09:05:33.900  INFO 43466
> --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 2022-07-24
> 09:05:34.211  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using
> JtaPlatform implementation:
> [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2022-07-24 09:05:34.224  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2022-07-24
> 09:05:34.408  INFO 43466 --- [           main]
> c.e.s.r.sourceformat.FindAllTests        : Started FindAllTests in
> 2.997 seconds (JVM running for 4.157)
>
> ## ============================ CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
>
> 2022-07-24 09:05:34.432 ERROR 43466 --- [           main]
> o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while
> allowing TestExecutionListener
> [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@c430e6c]
> to prepare test instance
> [com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests@6f43c82]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
> ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
> at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
> ~[spring-test-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
> ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
> at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2] Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
> ... 72 common frames omitted
>
> [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time
> elapsed: 3.564 s <<< FAILURE! - in
> com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests
> [ERROR] shouldReturnAll  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< ERROR!
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.FindAllTests':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.repositories.sourceformat.SourceFormatRepository'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0):

I made  multiple mistakes:

- the main class should be a top class. In my case it was `com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats.application` which isn't the recommended --> changed to `com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats`
- when I run tests I need to include `install` too
- IntelliJ sometimes not in sync with reality, many times I got compilation error from maven, but IntelliJ displayed no error. Removing `~/.m2/repository` and invalidating IntelliJ's cache helped
- `@DataJpaTest` uses `TestEntityManager` which for some reason throws `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist` making impossible to use seeding the database. Anyway, I generally use the repository own methods to seed the tables with data
- in tests, it seems, only `@AutoWired` is accepted. Constructor injection causes error. I don't like it, but it seems it is a package Spring gives you... :S

Now the application starts and serves the requests. Tests also running and they are green.